# Friendly warning when page doesn't exist

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building an offline version of one of our websites using phonegap. It's working fine, however there may be a time when I miss one of the links that's in the static html, and if clicked accidentally the app will fall over.

Is there a 'catch' for this, or something so i can pop up a message box saying something like "This is only a demo version, this link is disabled"

Thanks a lot for any help!

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the page exists by an ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.example.com/somefile.ext or relative path',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //file not exists
    },
    success: function()
    {
        //file exists
    }
});
```

Comment: That means changing every link to have that though, no?

Comment: Yes, each link with on click : pageExists(url) if file exists make a .replace() and go to the page. If file doesn't exists, an error page.

Comment: Cheers for the idea but > 2000 links I really can't be doing with changing them all manually

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler on click, check if the page exists, if not call event.preventDefault (go to the page) & stopPropagation

```
$('.classLink').on('click', function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can use `return false` to achieve the same result. From http://api.jquery.com/on/:

> Returning false from an event handler will automatically call
>   event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault(). A false value can
>   also be passed for the handler as a shorthand for function(){ return
>   false; }. So, $("a.disabled").on("click", false); attaches an event
>   handler to all links with class "disabled" that prevents them from
>   being followed when they are clicked and also stops the event from
>   bubbling.